# Nested ng-repeat issue with select/options drop down box

Tags: html, angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat that makes a call to an endpoint to grab a giant JSON object full of data, which is assigned to the vm via the controller.  Inside the vm object, there are several properties, including a property that has an array of objects, which in turn has a property that contains an array of objects.

In the example below (shortened version of what I'm working on), you can see the vm object, which contains a Students property, which contains an array of student objects, where each student has a grades property that further contains an array of objects that show a grade for a certain class and teacher.  The first ng-repeat creates rows in a table based on the Students, and the second ng-repeat is supposed to create a dropdown based on the grades of the student (see the HTML below as well).

```
{
    vm: { variousProperties...
          variousProperties...
          variousProperties...
          Students:
            [{ firstName: Alice
               grades:
                   [{
                     class: History
                     teacher: Mrs. History
                     grade: 96
                    },{
                      class: Math
                      teacher: Mrs. Math
                      grade: 97
                    }]
              }, {
                firstName: Beth
                grades:
                    [{
                      class: History
                      teacher: Mrs. History
                      grade: 92
                    ]}
            }]
        }
```

}

The basic code is as follows - the table rows are clickable, which drop down a sub area that contains additional information:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="student in vm.Students">
 <tr ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen"> <!--Create the rows and make them clickable so a sub area can drop down with different information-->
   <td> <!--clickable headers in the table-->  </td>
 </tr>

 <tr> <!--This is for the drop down for each row-->
   <table>
     <thead> <tr> <th> </th> </tr> </thead>
     <tbody> <tr>
       <div> <!--This div ends up holding everything, and is what appears when you click on a row in the table to drop down the additional information-->
       <select ng-model="vm.studentType">
         <option ng-repeat="grade in student.grades">
         </option>
       </select>
          <div> 
            <span>Class: {{grade.class}}<span><br>
            <span>Teacher: {{grade.teacher}}<span><br>
            <span>Grade: {{grades.grade}}<span><br>
          </div>
```

What I need to be able to do is click the row, drop down the additional div, and then have a dropdown options menu where I can select a student's grades based on the class.  Since the students might not all have the same classes, the second ng-repeat is needed to build a list of options that are specific to the student.  That way, I could click on Alice's row, see the sub area appear with the dropdown menu, and then select various options pertinent to that student **without changing the other rows for other students.**

However, I'm running into two problems.  I seemingly can't solve both at the same time:

1. I need the dropdown list to show an initial selection, **and** I need that initial selection to populate the spans accordingly.  So for Alice, it would initially select History, and then show History/Mrs. History/96 in the spans.  If I clicked the dropdown again, I could select her other class, and the spans populate accordingly.
2. I need to be able to select dropdown list items on a **per-student basis, so that changing Alice's options don't change Beth's**.

I've tried a number of different ways to do this, such as:

- Using track by $index and setting the value to $index
- Setting up an ng-model (vm.studentType), setting ng-model-options to updateOn default
- Changing the way the spans populate, such as using Student.grades[$index].class, or Student.grades[vm.studentType].class
- Tried setting up ng-init options, or initializing through the controller

For example, on the nested ng-repeat, I set ng-model to vm.studentType, track by $index, set value to $index, and make each span use Students.grades[vm.studentType].class, and so on.  This will populate the spans with the initial grade per student, **but** if I change Alice from History to Math, everything for Beth blanks out.  If after this I set Beth's back to her History, Alice's also resets to History.  So in this scenario, I need to be able to prevent both student's spans changing when I alter one or the other.  This suggests the vm.studentType set as the ng-model is not going to work, since it keeps updating for all students whenever I choose a new option.

Instead of setting ng-model to vm.studentType, I instead set it to $index (which I'm sure is not the intended setup) and keep the track by $index and value=$index all on the nested repeat, I can freely change the options between student without them interfering with others. However, this causes the drop downs to be blank themselves.  The spans will also be empty, with an exception of Alice, whose spans are initially populated.

So I need the drop down to show "Grade 1" or so initially, for the spans to be populated based on Grade 1, and then be able to freely change these on a per-student basis without interfering with other students.

I've tried fooling around with ng-model-options, using ng-option instead of separating the option from the select DOM element, tried using $parent.$index, console logged various things, printing out $index and $parent.$index using braces, etc.

I have messed with this for a few days now, and have asked coworkers as well for help, and cannot find an answer.

I apologize for some of my ignorance with Angular - I'm still in the learning phase and am just looking for some help.  Any consideration is appreciated, and thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: `ng-repeat="grades in Students.grades` don't you want to be looping through the inner `students` array here? Loop with the current iteration (`student`) you've created from the parent loop. Try `grades in student.grades` here.

Comment: I saw you edited it. You're closer, but still not looping through the right array here. You want lowercase `student`. Hopefully this helps: http://oi68.tinypic.com/15n828n.jpg apologies for the janky image.

Comment: Hi Antiga,

Aye, saw those things, and have made edits accordingly.  I appreciate the help so far!

Comment: So what's still the problem? Do you mind asking a little more succinctly? Specifically, with what you have now, what isn't working? You will find a lot more help when you can show you've made an effort (you did), show some code (you also did that), and quickly explain your problem. A lot of people will see a huge block of text and move on. If you respond here in the comment I'll be happy to post an answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work? Make vm.studentType an Object initialy in the controller. Instead of the $index you can use student.id.

```html
<tbody ng-repeat="student in vm.Students track by student.id">
 <tr ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen"> <!--Create the rows and make them clickable so a sub area can drop down with different information-->
   <td> <!--clickable headers in the table-->  </td>
 </tr>

 <tr> <!--This is for the drop down for each row-->
   <table>
     <thead> <tr> <th> </th> </tr> </thead>
     <tbody> <tr>
       <div> <!--This div ends up holding everything, and is what appears when you click on a row in the table to drop down the additional information-->
       <select ng-model="vm.studentType[$index]" ng-options="::grad.class for grade in ::student.grades">
       </select>
          <div> 
            <span>Class: {{vm.studentType[$index].class}}<span><br>
            <span>Teacher: {{vm.studentType[$index].teacher}}<span><br>
            <span>Grade: {{vm.studentType[$index].grade}}<span><br>
          </div>
```

Also use one time binding in ng-repeat where ever possible.
The use of track by will also improve performance on big lists if they can change.